# How to use sensu-plugins-aws?

Tags: chef-infra, sensu

I am new to sensu and writing chef cookbooks to monitor AWS cloudwatch metrics using [sensu-plugins-aws](https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-aws). I did`t understand from there README.

1. How this plugin works?
2. Is there any sample cookbooks using this plugin?
3. How could I use this to monitor the AWS cloudwatch metrics. Do I need to use the checks(standalone or subscription) or only the handler.

Comment: Do you know how to use sensu and this plugin itself as a first step ? This cookbook just aim at being an helper to configure the plugin, if you have no clue about sensu and this plugin beforehand, starting by their automation is not the right path.

Comment: @Tensibai Thanks for your attention. Though beginner, I have installed sensu & using various plugins for sensu checks using the cookbooks. But I don`t know how to use this aws plugin.